# VBA - How do exit a whole sub if a condition isn't true

Tags: vba, excel

I'm seeking for your help.
Well I have a sub divided in a lot of proc

```
Sub Go
Call Proc1
Call Proc2
Call Proc3
Call Proc4
End Sub
```

In the Proc1 I do the matching of values and I check if the cells are empty etc. So I want to Exit the Sub Go and stop the macro from running if any condition isn't true.

I tested End, Exit Sub but it just goes from the test 1 to the test 2.

Is there any method the go directly to the last End Sub (i.e Sub Go ! )

Comment: You could change your `Sub`s to `Function`s and make them return a value indicating if macro should be continued, and test that return value in you Sub Go.

Comment: You could also use error handling by raising an error in the Procx Subs and catching it in the Go Sub.

Comment: @VincentG haha I wish I could my code is already 4000 lgn.. The tests I'm doing are due to some misusing from the staff so I have to fix the values :/

Comment: Well, if it's a design flaw it might be better on the long way to solve it now if possible. A third way could be to use a global variable and set it when you want to exit, and test it after each call but I don't see how it could be easier that the 2 other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1: Changing Sub to Functions:**

```
Function Proc1() As Boolean
    'Do some check
    If SomeCheckAreWrong Then
        Proc1 = False
    Else
        'Normal treatment
        Proc1 = True
    End If
End Function

Sub Go()
    If Proc1 Then
        'do proc2 only if proc1 returned True
        If Proc2 Then
        '...
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Solution 2: Raising and catching error**

```
Sub Proc1()
    'Do some check
    If SomeCheckAreWrong Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1
    Else
        'Normal treatment
    End If
End Sub

Sub Go()
    On Error GoTo exit_with_error
    Proc1
    Proc2
    '...
exit_with_error:
End Sub
```

**Solution 3: With global variable**

```
Global DoNotContinue As Boolean
Sub Proc1()
    'Do some check
    If SomeCheckAreWrong Then
        DoNotContinue = True
    Else
        'Normal treatment
    End If
End Sub

Sub Go()
    DoNotContinue = False
    Proc1
    If DoNotContinue Then Exit Sub
    Proc2
    If DoNotContinue Then Exit Sub
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice set of options.

Comment: Note that I kept Go for the samples, but it is not a valid VBA name for a function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
Sub Main()
    If Not Proc1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Proc2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub

Function Proc1() As Boolean
    Dim matchVal As String

    matchVal = "A"

    Proc1 = IIf(Range("A1") = matchVal, True, False)
End Function

Function Proc2() As Boolean
    Dim matchVal As String

    matchVal = "B"

    Proc2 = IIf(Range("B1") = matchVal, True, False)
End Function
```

Each function returns a boolean i.e True | False. Use this to test for success and exit the sub if not.

Comment: Could also use nested ifs to ignore the following procedures if false returned:  `If Proc1 Then If Proc2 Then MsgBox "Complete"` as a single line, or `If Proc1 Then : If Proc2 Then : MsgBox "Complete" : End If : End If` using `If...End If` code blocks.

Comment: Or to make the single line more readable:  `If Proc1 And Proc2 Then MsgBox "Complete"`

Comment: Thank you Alex, but my Proc1/2/4  are subs and not functions

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook There is no Lasy evaluation in VBA, `If Proc1 And Proc2 Then MsgBox "Complete"` will evaluate Proc2 whatever the return value of Proc1 is

Comment: @MissMacro: Can you not change the subs to functions? The issue you have is that the procedures will be called regardless of success or failure within each sub. By using a function you get a return value to check against.

Comment: @VincentG Good point - was getting carried away on getting the Msgbox to display or not and forgot that each function would be evaluated to the TRUE/FALSE.  Even obviously did it when I stepped through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable as follows:

```
Public IsExit As Boolean

Sub Proc1()
    'your stuff here
    IsExit = True
End Sub

Sub Gom()
    IsExit = False
    Call Proc1
    If IsExit Then Exit Sub
    Call Proc2
    If IsExit Then Exit Sub
    Call Proc3
    If IsExit Then Exit Sub
    Call Proc4
End Sub
```